# How to put a n+1 value from a variable into another column at row n in case of multiple rows per ID in SAS?

Tags: loops, parsing, sas, do-while

I have a dataset which have various multiple rows per ID ordering by date.
I want to split my dataset for each row and put the value of the n+1 row date into another column at row n for each ID. If there is only one row for the ID the value will be already defined. Then i want to split my dataset for count=1 then count=2,etc... How can I do that in SAS?

```
   ID   date    end_period      age_end count
   1    n       n+1             value    1
   1    n+1     N+2             value    2
   1    N+2     n+3             value    3
   1    n+3     value(age_end)  value    4
   2    n       value(age_end)  value    1
```

Comment: So this is a look ahead problem?  You want to compute end_period?  I suggest you show the data you HAVE to start with (with real actual values, not n+1 etc, and show the data you WANT to create. Sounds like maybe you want to create the end_period variable, and then create four output datasets?

Answer (score 0):

As Quentin mentioned it is kind of hard to tell without seeing some sample data. I kind of am understanding like they had mentioned that you need to create 2 fields. If, and a huge IF, your date is a SAS date then you can simply do this...

```
end_period = date + 1;
```

If it is not, I would recommend converting a number or text to a SAS date.

If Count is not a field in your data set then simply sorting and doing by group processing can easily calculate that

```
data dsn_final;
   set dsn_name;
   by ID Date;
   if first.ID then Count=1;
   else Count+1;
run;
```

Finally the splitting into separate data sets. If there is an unknown max Count... meaning you don't know the max row for any of the IDs in the data set being that it is too large, or possibly changing then I'd recommend using a macro to create the separate data sets. First find the max and store it in a macro variable. Then split the data set based in count going up to the max count.

```
proc sql noprint;
    select max(count)
           into: max_count
    from simulate;
quit;

%put &max_count.;

%macro datasets;
data %do count=1 %to &max_count; 
        date&count. (drop=count) 
    %end; ;
set simulate;
    %do count=1 %to &max_count;
        if count = &count. then output date&count.;
    %end;
run;
%mend;
%datasets;
```

If you respond back with samples of data then there are possibly easier ways, but to my understanding you needed to calculate 2 fields and then split. The split will be easier if you know the max. I'd only use the macro if it is unknown or possibly using in the future and the data changes with max count possibly changing.